# Jenkins Matrix job with commas

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to make a jenkins job that uses a Configuration Matrix in order to build multiple versions of my application using different maven profiles. My initial idea was to create a bunch of configurations under the guise of a profile like:

XXX,YYY,ZZZ

XXX,YYY,AAA

then as the build command use:
mvn -P $profile

To get all the different builds.

Sadly this does not seem to work, Jenkins gets confused seemingly by the use of commas in the configuartion matrix. I tried seeing if url encoding worked (it got further but the actual maven command failed because it contained the url encoded version of commas which confused maven).

I realise I could put in a pointless character that is allowed and then in a script replace it with a comma, but that doesn't seem correct. There has to be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Your right, this looks like a bug. I am also unable to use a value with a comma. Could you try to set a jvm parameter (-D) to activate one or the other profile?

Comment: you can vote for it if you want it to be fixed quickly: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16055

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple Maven profiles without using commas with `-Pprofile1 -Pprofile2` and use quotes to escape the spaces.

My configuration matrix looks like this:

[image]

The maven command is

[image: Maven Command]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried spaces instead of commas ?

The Help link says `Values assigned to variables. Multiple values are separated by whitespace or newlines. Use shell quoting syntax for a value that contains whitespace.`

[image: Screenshot from Jenkins matrix configuration]

Comment: and you must have explored `escape sequence` options already, I am guessing

Comment: I said "I tried seeing if url encoding worked (it got further but the actual maven command failed because it contained the url encoded version of commas which confused maven)"